# What is the proper way to call Rx-java Observable methods?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java

I defined a following method in `Wrapper` class for making `Rest` call.

```
public void getWarehouse(){

    //Generation of  RestAdapter
    RestAdapter adapter = new  RestAdapter.Builder ()
            .setEndpoint(URL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();

    //Making request to API
    adapter.create(WarehouseAPI.class).getWarehouse()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Warehouse>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "OnCompleted()");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Error: "  + e.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Warehouse> response) {
                }
            });
}
```

Above code is working fine and I am getting an expected response. But I need to call this method from an `Adapter class`. How can I do that? Is there any way that I can use `onNext` method?

I am beginner in `Android rx-java` and `Retrofit`.

## Edit-1

I am using `staggeredGridView` to show the data. So, In my `MainActivity` class I am calling following code:

```
 StaggeredGridAdapter adapter = new StaggeredGridAdapter(this);
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To fill the data in `StaggeredGridView holder` I have to call `getWarehouse` method.

## Edit-2

MainActivity's `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    getWarehouse();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.staggering_grid);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    StaggeredGridAdapter adapter = new StaggeredGridAdapter(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    GridItemSpaces decoration = new GridItemSpaces(10);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);

}
```

Where `StaggeredGridAdapter` is:

```
public class StaggeredGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StaggeredGridAdapter.StaggeredGridView>{}
```

## Edit-3

After the suggestion I call `getWarehouse();` in `MainActivity.onCreate` method  and copy the definition of `getWarehouse()` to `MainActivity.class`.

Also my `MainActivity.getWarehouse.onNext` method:

```
@Override
public void onNext(List<Warehouse> response) {
  mAdapter.addItems(response);
}
```

Where as `mAdapter` is `private StaggeredGridAdapter mAdapter;` which is initialized later in `MainActivity.onCreate` method.

What would be the definition of `addItems` method in `StaggeredGridAdapter` class?

## Edit-4

Full definition of `StaggeredGridAdapter`

```
public class StaggeredGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StaggeredGridAdapter.StaggeredGridView> {
private Context context;
private List<Warehouse> warehouses = new ArrayList<Warehouse>();
int size;

public StaggeredGridAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void addItems(List<Warehouse> response){
    size = response.size();
    warehouses = response;
}

@Override
public StaggeredGridView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
    StaggeredGridView staggeredGridView = new StaggeredGridView(layoutView);
    return staggeredGridView;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StaggeredGridView holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(warehouses.get(position).getFace());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return size;
}

class StaggeredGridView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;

    public StaggeredGridView(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_name);

    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need to call it from an Adapter ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Please have a look at the Edit-1 section

Comment: no you don't. Your Activity deals with the `getWarehouse`. When you get the `onNext` you update your Adapter with the new data.

Comment: Can you please give me an example or link where i can see it

Comment: you keep a reference to the Adapter, and then use the reference to call an arbitrary `add` method. Where did you get the `StaggeredGridAdapter` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Please have a look at the Edit-2 section

Comment: so it is pretty easy to expose a `public` method to add items to the underlying collection

Comment: So, What will you suggest then?

Comment: you keep `getWarehouse` in your Activity. In the same Activity you can keep a reference to StaggeredGridAdapter as you did with `mRecyclerView`. Create a `public void addItems(List<Warehouse> response)`  in your Adapter, and when onNext is called you simply do `mAdapter.addItems(response)`

Comment: @Blackbelt Please have a look at Edit-3 section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would leave the `getWarehouse()` in the `Activity` . In the same Activity you can keep a reference to StaggeredGridAdapter as you did with mRecyclerView. Create a `public void addItems(List<Warehouse> response)` in your Adapter, and when onNext is called you simply do `mAdapter.addItems(response)`

E.g.

```
 public void addItems(List<Warehouse> items) {
     int oldSize = mDataSet.size();
     synchronized(mDataSet) {
         mDataSet.addAll(items);
     }
     notifyItemRangeInserted(oldSize - 1, mDataSet.size() - 1);
 }
```

where I am assuming that `mDataSet` is the name of the `Collection` you are using in your Adapter (your dataset).

I would also avoid to instantiate

```
   RestAdapter adapter = new  RestAdapter.Builder ()
            .setEndpoint(URL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
```

everytime you call `getWarehouse();`. `subscribe` returns a `Subscription` object. Keep it as member variable and call unsubscribe in your ondDestroy

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mSubscription != null) {
        mSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with the above approach is `StaggeredGridAdapter .getItem` is get called before the response of `Retrofit Async call`. Am I doing something wrong here. I have added StaggeredGridAdapter class in Edit-4 section and onCreate method in `Edit-2` section

Answer (score 0):

Rather than subscribing within the getWarehouse method, have getWarehouse return the observable and do the subscribe part in the adapter.  This way you can have the onNext callback exist in the adapter and not in the calling method. Ideally you should instantiate the restadapter only once rather than everytime within the getWarehouse method as well.

```
public Observable<Warehouse> getWarehouse(){

adapter.getWarehouse()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

}

from adapter do this:
`someClass.getWarehouse().subscribe(new Subscriber()....)`